# Error intelephense de VSCode: Expected type 'mysqli'

Tags: php, vscode

Estoy desarrollando un sistema PHP que contiene 2 archivos. ConnectClass.php y MethodsClass.php. En ConectaClass.php, se encuentra el siguiente código:

```
class ConectaClass{

private $servidor = 'localhost';
private $usuario = 'usuario';
private $senha = 'clave';
private $banco = 'banco_datos';

protected $conecta;

public function conectar()
{
    $this->conecta = mysqli_connect($this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->senha,$this->banco);
    mysqli_set_charset($this->conecta, "utf8");
    try
    {
        if (mysqli_connect_errno() != 0) 
        {
            $e = $this->erro(mysqli_connect_error());
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
            else
        {
            return $this->conecta;
        }
    }
        catch(Exception $e)
    {
    $this->conecta = 'Error CODPT_I: 0001';
    return $this->conecta;
    }
  } 
}
```

El método MethodsClass.php se ve así:

```
include("ConectaClass.php");

class MetodosClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     $conectar = new conectaClass();
     $this->conexao = $conectar->conectar();
     return $this->conexao;
  }

  public function validaUsuarios($loginUsuario,$senhaUsuario)
  {
     ....
     mysqli_query($this->conexao,'SELECT * FROM...');
  }
}
```

Estoy usando VS Code para desarrollar y se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con los siguientes problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sistema funciona normalmente, pero me gustaría solucionar este problema. ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: No hay errores en esas líneas cuando intento reproducir el problema en mi VS. Tal vez falte algún Plugin de VSC para que no te marque esa línea como error.

Comment: Hola Liyo. Verdad. Estoy usando PHP Intelephense de Ben Mewburn.

Comment: ¿Puede indicarme otra extensión?

Comment: Yo utilizo la misma y PHP Debug de xdebug.org